# Loader output fixed file name

Tags: node.js, webpack

Configuration file look like below

```
{ test: /\.testfile\.ttf(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" }
```

but when run, it will generated  [hash].ttf in output folder. how to output with same input filename without hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [file-loader api](https://github.com/webpack/file-loader)

So wherever you're requiring that file in your components/stylesheet just do `require("file?name=[name].[ext]!./testfile.ttf");` (simply just the path to testfile.ttf as appropriate)

`[name]` will output the same basename as your input resource

`[ext]` will output the extension of your input resource

Alternatively, you can just add query parameters onto your configuration

```
{ test: /\.testfile\.ttf(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader?name=[name].[ext]" }
```